# How to hide and unhide form fields based on a radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to implement a radio button, which if clicked should get more options for the user to fill in.

Here's what I've tried.

```
<script>
  function addmentor() {
    if ( document.getElementById("type_Computer").checked ) {
    document.getElementById('nextSetOfComputerOptions').style.display = "";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('nextSetOfComputerOptions').style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="type" id="type_computer" value="Computer"  onClick="addmentor()">Add    Mentor</button>
<div id="nextSetOfComputerOptions" style="display:none;">
.
.
</div>
```

The above code doesn't work. When I am clicking the radio button, nothing happens, the part of the form is always hidden.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the browser developer tools. It shows an error in your case, unable to fetch an element. The reason is you try to fetch `type_Computer`, while the id of the element is actually `type_computer` (lowercase - case is important!).

Comment: Okay, that was it. It works now.. Please post it as an answer. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not posting an answer though. Typo questions are meant to be closed, not answered (site policy).

Comment: See my updated answer. @El_Vanja was correct, you were using the wrong id for the element you declared. In addition, I have simplified your code a bit and included a function to hide inputs if another radio button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I originally misunderstood the question and have now adjusted my answer.

Additionally, I have also included a function that will hide your input if another radio button is clicked.

See the snippet below:

```js
//your checkbox
var checkbox = document.getElementById("type_computer");

//your div
var inputDiv = document.getElementById("nextSetOfComputerOptions");

//function that will show hidden inputs when clicked
function addmentor() {
  if (checkbox.checked = true) {
    inputDiv.style.display = "block";
  }
}

//function that will hide the inputs when another checkbox is clicked
function hideInputDiv() {
  inputDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" id="type_computer" value="Computer" onChange="addmentor();" ">Add Mentor</input>
<input type="radio" name="type" onClick="hideInputDiv();">Other radio input</input>
<div id="nextSetOfComputerOptions" style="display: none;">
  <input placeholder="PC"></input>
  <input placeholder="Mac"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply appending to body would place that element at the end of the page. What if more elements come after the radio button? It'd be more sensible to append to a close container.

Comment: Plus, that's half the job. If that radio gets more options, you'd have to have a method that removes this additional input once "Add mentor" is no longer the selected option.

Comment: Thanks for your input. - I've adjusted my snippet. Ideally, we would run a loop for each radio button IF there were multiple radio buttons and hide the inputs accordingly. However, the question does not mention multiple radio buttons. I believe the updated snippet now adequately answers the overbearing question "How to hide and unhide form fields based on a radio button?" - Additionally, just for the sake of predictability, I have included a simple function to hide the inputs if another radio button was clicked.